# JOIN SubQuery in @nest/sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I would like to get a rating for each movie

This query works as it should

```
SELECT *
FROM movie
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "movieId", avg(score), count("userId")
    FROM rating
    GROUP BY rating."movieId"
) AS rating ON rating."movieId" = movie.id 
WHERE movie.title ilike '%Titanic%'
LIMIT 10
```

The code I have now

```
return this.movieRepo.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: {
      title: { [Op.iLike]: '%' + query + '%' },
      author: { [Op.iLike]: '%' + query + '%' },
      publisher: { [Op.iLike]: '%' + query + '%' },
    },
  },
  limit,
  offset: (page - 1) * limit,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to use two subqueries in `attributes` option using `Sequelize.literal`:

```js
return this.movieRepo.findAndCountAll({
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [Sequelize.literal('(SELECT AVG(rating.score) FROM rating WHERE rating."movieId"=movie.id)'), 'avg_score'],
      [Sequelize.literal('(SELECT count(rating."userId") FROM rating WHERE rating."movieId"=movie.id)'), 'cnt_user']
    ]
  },
  where: {
    [Op.or]: {
      title: { [Op.iLike]: '%' + query + '%' },
      author: { [Op.iLike]: '%' + query + '%' },
      publisher: { [Op.iLike]: '%' + query + '%' },
    },
  },
  limit,
  offset: (page - 1) * limit,
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the diploma will be written a little faster!

Comment: Can I now sort by rating? In regular sql, it's only obtained through a subquery SELECT * FROM (-all previous query-) AS m ORDER BY "avg_score" DESC (~2 seconds), without this it takes a very long time. I don't understand how to implement it in Sequelize

Comment: You just need  to use the same literal in `order` option as well